# Extract string and symbols with splitting

Tags: scala

```
   1. ABC <= 123   // lower= null, name = ABC, upper = 123
   2. 456 < DEF    // lower= 456, name = DEF, upper = null
   3. 345 < THJ <= 987  // lower= 345, name = THJ, upper = 987
```

I have these type of strings I want to split it and get the values like this template

```
lower < name <= upper
```

I have written the below scala code and it is working. But I think This can be done in more efficient way

```
val str = "4 < ABC <= 654"

        val strSplitted: Array[String] = str.split("<=")
        var lower= null
        var name = null
        var upper= null

        if (strSplitted.head.nonEmpty) {
            val w_first = strSplitted.head.split("<")

            if (w_first.nonEmpty && w_first.size > 1) {
                lower= w_first.head
                name = w_first.tail.head
                if (strSplitted.size > 1)
                    upper= strSplitted.tail.head
            }
            else {
                name = strSplitted.head
                upper= strSplitted.tail.head
            }
        }
        else {
            val w_first = str.split("<")
            lower= w_first.head
            name = w_first.tail.head
        }
        println("lower:" + lower)
        println("name :" + name )
        println("upper:" + upper)
```

Comment: Is it the constant format? Or this can be repeated?  Is 1. 2. 3. Are part of string?  If the pattern can repeat how long the string can be?

Comment: 1. 2. 3. is not a part of string

Comment: @RamanMishra Format is constant. and above 3 are the possible formats

Comment: I'm removing the java tag as this looks like just a scala question. Feel free to revert if the tag was meant to be there though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are lots of ways you could write this more concisely or efficiently, but I think one especially nice one uses Scala's regular expression extractors:

```
case class Result(name: String, lower: Option[Long], upper: Option[Long])

val UpperOnly = """(\w+)\s<=\s(\d+)""".r
val LowerOnly = """(\d+)\s<\s(\w+)""".r
val Both = """(\d+)\s<\s(\w+)\s<=\s(\d+)""".r

def parse(input: String): Option[Result] = input match {
  case Both(lb, name, ub) => Some(Result(name, Some(lb.toLong), Some(ub.toLong)))
  case UpperOnly(name, ub) => Some(Result(name, None, Some(ub.toLong)))
  case LowerOnly(lb, name) => Some(Result(name, Some(lb.toLong), None))
  case _ => None
}
```

And then:

```
scala> parse("ABC <= 123")
res0: Option[Result] = Some(Result(ABC,None,Some(123)))

scala> parse("456 < DEF")
res1: Option[Result] = Some(Result(DEF,Some(456),None))

scala> parse("345 < THJ <= 987")
res2: Option[Result] = Some(Result(THJ,Some(345),Some(987)))

scala> parse("bad string")
res3: Option[Result] = None
```

You can make it more strict (requiring names to be upper-case, etc.) or more lenient (allowing arbitrary amounts of white space) as needed.

You could also get a little more clever with optional pieces in the regex and only have a single matching case, but I think the version above provides a better balance of clarity and efficiency.

(Note that while this handles some bad inputs, like the last example, it will explode on e.g. `Long` overflow. That's easy enough to fix if needed.)

Comment: What about having one regex with optional groups?
`val r = raw"(?:(\d*) < )?(\w*)(?: <= (\d*))?".r` it will return `null` for missing values _(which is quite ugly)_, but you can always wrap them in an `Option` to have the same effect than your answer.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Yeah, that's what I mean by the "more clever" part. Sure, it's possible, but I think the version I've provided is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit rough around the edges (for example: the spaces between symbols are required), but it demonstrates the possibility of a regex solution.

```
def parse(s :String) :(String,String,String) = {
  val RE = raw"([^\s]+)\s+(?:< ([^\s]+))?\s?(?:<= ([^\s]+))?".r.unanchored
  s match {
    case RE(a, b, c) => if (b == null) (null, a, c) else (a, b, c)
    case _ => (null, null, null)
  }
}
```

testing:

```
parse("ABC <= 123")       //res0: (String, String, String) = (null,ABC,123)
parse("456 < DEF")        //res1: (String, String, String) = (456,DEF,null)
parse("345 < THJ <= 987") //res2: (String, String, String) = (345,THJ,987)
```

usage:

```
val (lower, name, upper) = parse(inputString)
```

Comment: I prefer my answer but think this one is reasonable (I'm not the downvoter).